# Raspberry Pi serdev driver never reaches probe function

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I want to write a minimal serdev Linux driver on a Raspberry Pi. Therefore I have to enable the kernel option SERIAL_DEV_CTRL_TTYPORT, but I don't know how. I have tried various options, but my Kernel Module never reaches the Probe function...

Here is what I got already:

I tried to enable the option by changing the /boot/cmdline.txt to:

```
SERIAL_DEV_CTRL_TTYPORT SERIAL_DEV_CTRL_TTYPORT=y SERIAL_DEV_CTRL_TTYPORT=yes root=PARTUUID=8d696e29-02 rootfstype=ext4 fsck.repair=yes rootwait modules-load=dwc2,g_ether
```

The device tree overlay:

```
/dts-v1/;
/plugin/;
/ {
        compatible = "brcm,bcm2835";
        fragment@0 {
                target = <&uart0>;
                status = "okay";
                __overlay__ {
                        my_device {
                                compatible = "brightlight,echodev";
                                status = "okay";
                        };
                };
        };
};
```

The Kernel Module:

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/serdev.h>
#include <linux/mod_devicetable.h>
#include <linux/property.h>
#include <linux/platform_device.h>
#include <linux/of_device.h>

/* Meta Information */
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("Johannes 4 GNU/Linux");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("A simple serdev example");

/* Declate the probe and remove functions */
static int dt_probe(struct serdev_device *serdev);
static void dt_remove(struct serdev_device *serdev);

static struct of_device_id my_driver_ids[] = {
        {
                .compatible = "brightlight,echodev",
        }, { /* sentinel */ }
};
MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE(of, my_driver_ids);

static struct serdev_device_driver my_driver = {
        .probe = dt_probe,
        .remove = dt_remove,
        .driver = {
                .name = "echodev",
                .of_match_table = my_driver_ids,
        },
};

/**
 * @brief This function is called on loading the driver
 */
static int dt_probe(struct serdev_device *serdev) {
        printk("my_serdev - Now I am in the probe function!");
        return 0;
}

/**
 * @brief This function is called on unloading the driver
 */
static void dt_remove(struct serdev_device *serdev) {
        printk("my_serdev - Now I am in the remove function\n");
}

module_serdev_device_driver(my_driver);
```

Do you have any tips?

UPDATE 1:

I checked my Kernel .config file and found out, that CONFIG_SERIAL_DEV_CTRL_TTYPORT is already set and enabled. I double checked it with

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo modprobe configs
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ gzip -d /proc/config.gz --stdout | grep SERIAL_DEV
CONFIG_SERIAL_DEV_BUS=y
CONFIG_SERIAL_DEV_CTRL_TTYPORT=y
```

But then, why does my module never reaches the probe function???

Best regards,
Johannes

Comment: CONFIG_SERIAL_DEV_CTRL_TTYPORT  is a compile-time option for the kernel.

Comment: Ok, make sense. But is there a way to enable this dynamically while loading the kernel? E.g. to manipulate CONFIG_IO_STRICT_DEVMEM you can use the kernel parameter iomem=relaxed. Is there something similar to manipulate CONFIG_SERIAL_DEV_CTRL_TTYPORT?

Comment: No, you must use the kernel's `.config` generation (e.g. `drivers/tty/serdev/Kconfig`) and respond Y to: `"Serial device bus"` and `"Serial device TTY port controller"` questions. Then, rebuild/reboot the kernel. You can look at the existing `.config` to see if it's already enabled. So, `menuconfig` et. al. commands. It's already enabled on my stock fedora kernel

Comment: Ok, I checked in `/usr/src/5.15.32+/.config` and `CONFIG_SERIAL_DEV_CTRL_TTYPORT`is set to y there. I also tried `modprobe configs`to get the configs and check with `gzip -d /proc/config.gz --stdout | grep SERIAL_DEV` and got:
`CONFIG_SERIAL_DEV_BUS=y`
`CONFIG_SERIAL_DEV_CTRL_TTYPORT=y`

But why do I never reach the probe function?

Comment: "*I checked my Kernel .config ... I double checked it with ...*" -- So you know that some config entries are *configured* to be built-in modules.  Did you verify that the object file of your driver was *built*? I.E. check for a **.o** file, and grep the **Image** file for unique driver strings such as `"my_serdev - Now I am in the probe function!"`.  "*why does my module never reaches the probe function?*" -- Did you review the boot log for salient messages? Did you inspect **/proc/device-tree** on the RPi to confirm that the overlay was properly applied?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got it, but I don't know exactly why it is working know.

When posting this example, I used `dtoverlay` to load the device tree overlay:

```
sudo dtoverlay testoverlay.dtbo
```

When doing so, I couldn't reach the probe function. Then I copied my overlay to /boot/overlays and added it to /boot/config.txt:

```
dtoverlay=testoverlay
```

And after a reboot, I inserted my kernel module and it reached the probe function. Does anyone know why this works now but not before?

Comment: I guess it never worked because resources had already been claimed by the TTY layer. Check the kernel log.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I watched [this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wIQPb1NkZbQ). And if a serial device doesn't have a child node, the TTY Driver will be loaded (and I can use it as a normal tty). But if a child node is present, no tty driver will be loaded and I can use it with my serdev driver, but it disappears in /dev/tty*.